# Can you change the rear hub on a tubular cyclo cross wheelset with out riping the tubular tyre off?

Tags: wheel-building, sram

I recently bought sram cx1 for my cyclocross bike and was hoping it to put it on tonight.

I didn't do enough research before purchasing the product to realise that 11 speed cassettes will not fit onto 10 speed hubs.

Can the rear hub on my tubular race wheels be changed with out ripping off the tubular tyre (and saving the expense of buying a new one)?

Comment: Bummer.  By they time you buy a wheel you might be over 1/2 way to the cost of a new bike.   If you can wait the to end of CX season you find some really good deals on CX  bikes.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, I have returned the things I bought and have hopefully learnt my lesson and will properly research my next purchases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is almost impossible to rebuild a wheel (i.e., new hub and new spokes) without removing the tire. Leaving the tire on, would mean leaving the spoke nipples in place.  (It is a good idea to replace the spoke nipples when rebuilding a wheel.  You will also require new spokes).  It is a big hassle threading the spoke into nipples that are stuck in one position.  Almost all wheel builders will first remove the tire.  It should be possible to [carefully remove](http://roadragecycling.com/2013/02/tubular-tire-removal-quick-guide.html) and reuse your tubular tire anyway, so this may be less of an issue than you think. (What adhesive did you use?)

### 11-speed compatibility options

In terms of replacing your hub to get 11 speed compatibility.  There are a few different options to consider.  Custom wheel builds are not cheap.  If your rims are not in pristine condition or insanely expensive it may be more cost effective to sell your wheels (or wheelset) and buy purchase a replacement wheelset that is 11 speed compatible. (Note an 11-speed rear wheel can take 10-speed cassettes with the appropriate spacer). You may also check what rear hub you have, some more recent hubs that started their life as 8/9/10 speed hubs were designed to allow the cassette freehub bodies to be changed in order to enable 11-speed compatibility (although this is *not* a common feature, it does exist and you may be lucky enough to own one).

Comment: +1. I'll add, that trying to lace spokes into nipples stuck by a tube can cause a puncture - at some moment you will push the nipple to much inside and pinch the tube.

Answer (score 2):

One option you're not considering is that the freehub body on your wheelset maybe be upgradable. Given you don't say what wheels they are but I assume given they're almost certainly disc hubs to use cx1 you may find this is an option. If you update saying what wheels you have on the rear and what hub it is then it's a good start